# Add a percentage (%) symbol to input value, but not pass with form

Tags: nouislider

I currently have nouislider working fine. However I would like to add a postfix "%" symbol to my input fields, to show the user that the value is a percentage value, and the problem I'm having is that the value being passed with the form includes the % symbol. Does anyone know a workaround so that only the value is passed with the form?

An alternative method that I tried, to the format:wNumb method suggested in the nouislider documentation is as follows:

```
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    moistureValues[handle].value = values[handle] + '%';
});
```

However this is still appending the percentage symbol to the url. Is there any other way that would solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the input is the value that is submitted, this is how the basic feature in HTML works. You have some options:

- Place the `%` sign in a `<span>` after the input.
- use `addEventListener('submit', ...)` on the form, capture the submit, then change the input value and re-submit it (using `.submit()`).
- Displaying the entire value in a span, and using a separate (hidden) input for the submit value.

(disclosure: I'm the lead developer for this libary).

Comment: Leon, thank you, the third option is the best one for sure. I tried putting the `%` sign after the input, but aesthetically it's not the best solution. Great slider and support!

Answer (score -2):

You are changing the `value` while you only need to change the `style` of the element:

```
connectBar.style[side] = offset + '%';
```

Full example:

```
var connectSlider = document.getElementById('connect');

 noUiSlider.create(connectSlider, {
    start: [20, 80],
    connect: false,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
});    

var connectBar = document.createElement('div'),
    connectBase = connectSlider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-base')[0],
    connectHandles = connectSlider.getElementsByClassName('noUi-origin');

// Give the bar a class for styling and add it to the slider.
connectBar.className += 'connect';
connectBase.appendChild(connectBar);

connectSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

    // Pick left for the first handle, right for the second.
    var side = handle ? 'right' : 'left',
    // Get the handle position and trim the '%' sign.
        offset = (connectHandles[handle].style.left).slice(0, - 1);

    // Right offset is 100% - left offset
    if ( handle === 1 ) {
        offset = 100 - offset;
    }

    connectBar.style[side] = offset + '%';
});
```

See the example here: https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-custom-connect

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, at all.